# Login to system in iphone.

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, authentication, asihttprequest

I am new in iphone internet programming. I am writing an app which has **login screen.**

I am using ASIHTTPREQUEST, this is the link myurl.com/index.php  what I want to login. In chrome,  I looked at from the developer console this url posts to myurl.com/ajax/login.php when I login the system with username and password.

Anyway, when I click the login button after entering username and password in app, it doesn't login the system.It prints the **FAIL:1 ( when I write myurl.com/ajax/login.php, FAIL:1** seen in the browser.)

**Detailed description of my problem:**

"There is an login screen in myurl.com/index.php. And in web browser, if I write my username and passw, It posts to myurl.com/ajax/login.php ( from the developer console). Anyway, in app I have written myurl.com/index.php as a url but when I request it prints the html elements of that page in console. If I write myurl.com/ajax/login.php as a url, it prints FAIL:1 in console. ( normally in web browser I have written myurl.com/ajax/login.php, it gives an FAIL:1)"

**Edit: I have solved problem, "forKey: @"username" need to be equal "forKey: @"ID" and "forKey: @"password" need to be equal "forKey: @"PWD". Because in developer console username and password returned as a ID and PWD. Thanks for comment and answer.**

This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender 
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://myurl.com/index.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
    [request setPostValue:studentid.text forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:starspassword.text forKey:@"password"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    [url release];
}

-(void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    UIAlertView *alert= [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"http works" 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS: %@", responseString);
    //Request succeeded
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex         
{
}

-(void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    UIAlertView *alert= [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"fail" message:@"http fails" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles:nil]autorelease];
    [alert show];
    //Request failed
}
```

Sorry for my english, there are some examples about this topic but I didn't solve this problem. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please add the error-message you see (the NSLog output).

Comment: I edited the last part of the question

Comment: I did expect to read the exact output of that NSLog statement from your code that starts with ERROR:

Comment: It doesn't give an error, I gives an SUCCESS: FAIL:1 so responseString is FAIL:1, If I write myurl.com/ajax/login.php in web browser, It gives an FAIL:1

Comment: Are you sure the login is supposed to work via HTTP-post? Maybe it is an old fashioned HTTP-auth (see shabzco's answer). You will need to tell us more about that login.

Comment: As I know, it is not old fashioned HTTP auth. There is an login screen in myurl.com/index.php. And in web browser, if I write my username and passw, It posts to myurl.com/ajax/login.php ( from the developer console). Anyway, in app I have written myurl.com/index.php as a url but when I request it prints the html elements of that page in console. If I write myurl.com/ajax/login.php as a url, it prints FAIL:1 in console. ( normally in web browser I have written myurl.com/ajax/login.php, it gives an FAIL:1)

Comment: That might be happening because that site checks for the referrer for preventing what you are trying to do (login attempts that do not come from their webpages). You need to fully understand the mechanisms  behind that authentication.

Comment: As a last resort, how about logging every single detail that is happening - use Charles HTTP Proxy when logging on that website via a desktop browser. Once you checked all the details (including the HTTP-headers being transmitted), mimic that exact same data using ASIHTTP-Request in your iOS App.

Comment: ok I will try charles proxy thnks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead? ASI includes a way to do basic authentication

```
[request setUsername:studentid.text];
[request setPassword:starspassword.text];
```

Scroll down to Handling HTTP Authentication

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: I tried but it didn't login system again :/, when I write myurl.com/ajax/login.php as a URL then FAIL:1 prints in the console.( If I write myurl.com/ajax/login.php in web browser, It gives an FAIL:1 again)